# Ruby: strange error while installing the bundler gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I just wanted to install the bundler gem.

I have no problems installing it. But when I install it and hit "bundle ", I get "command 'bundle' not found". When I then enter again "gem install bundler" it installs bundler again, without saying it'd be already installed.

I can install it again and again and again, but cannot use/access it.

I have no clue what's up with rubygems.

Yours, Joern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joe, that happens when gem installs the binary file in a folder that it's not in the path. try doing this to know where it was installed (it might take a few minutes)

```
find . | egrep "/bundle$"
```

and then add that folder to your path.

Comment: Why would `gem install bundle` not be installing it to a location in the path? How can you fix it so that it *does* do that?

Comment: rubygems installs all gems the right way, except this (important) one

Comment: the command you told me brings nothing... this tells me rubygems fails completely installing bundler, I'm used to get it install while installing rails 3, strangely this time it hasn't

Comment: @Andrew, unfortunately, I don't know the answer :(. I've hit this problem before, and the only solution was to add the folder to the path.

Comment: `find / . | egrep "/bundle$"` does the trick... "/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/bundle" is the location (this is right and usual, isn't it?)

Comment: not really, it should install the executables in one of the usual places, such as /usr/bin, /usr/local/bin (this doesn't apply if you're using rvm). Open you .profile, .bash_rc or .bash_profile and add that folder to your path.

Answer (score 0):

I just tracked down my solution to the same problem above not referenced elsewhere so I'm putting it here. In addition to adding the path to bundler gem, on Ubuntu 10.10 I had to use the shell command $ export RUBYOPT=rubygems in order for this to work.